# error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'appium-adb' after update to Appium 1.4.13

Tags: ios, testing, automation, appium

I'm getting 'error: uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'appium-adb' date=Fri Oct 16 2015 12:41:39 GMT-0700 (PDT)'  after updating Appium to 1.4.13 if anyone else seeing it? If anyone has suggestion what might cause it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I were able to launch simulator successfully following an idea of Hari Nallani post above, but instead of copying 4 folders, I did copy and paste this only "**appium-adb**" folder . Error happens because alias is wrong to this folder, please see image below, delete appium-adb allies file, after that drag and drop folder with a name "appium-adb" from the submodules, path is "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules"  into "node_modules" folder, path is "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules"  path. Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I come across this same error in mac for the appium.app.

1. Navigate to Following path:
   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/
2. it consists of folders appium-adb, appium-instruments, appium-uiauto, appium-atom etc....Observe that instead of actual content these are shortcuts.
3. Navigate to this path: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules
4. Observe that all the shortcut folder content is here so copy those folders specified in step 2 and paste to the path specified in step 1

it may work for windows as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! After following your steps I'm getting errors "info: [debug] [INST STDERR] dyld: could not load inserted library '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7/InstrumentsShim.dylib' because no suitable image found.  /InstrumentsShim.dylib
, in the end error message: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Instruments crashed on startup"

Comment: What version of Xcode you have? are you trying with simulator or Actual device? I think simulator. Try launching simulator from Xcode first then try launching appium. if it doesn't work then you may to fix opening simulator from Xcode. If the above doesn't work check to upgrade your Xcode version. I had Xcode 7.0.1 when I upgraded my Appium to 1.4.13. Further, instruments crash is related to your simulator which is not available in instruments library.

Comment: Additionally, try launching Appium with Android. If it launches then it is related to IOS simulator issue rather than Appium server configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your last post. Glad to hear that it is resolved now. In my first message, my suggestion is to copy folder(s) which was not having actual content rather shortcut(s). In my case, there were 4 folders.

Comment: For some reason copying 4 folder didn't work for me as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Anyway thank you for the fix/tip! It is working for me now and I'm glad! I need iOS only, so I don't cares about Android.